# trying to do operation on two files in Shell

Tags: shell

txt and two.txt as below

```
One.txt

jobid    Size
1        11
2        22
3        33 
4        44

Two.txt

jobid    Size
5        55
6        66
3        77 
4        88
```

Now I want to find common fields in those two files in the jobid column which are 3 & 4 and subtract their size value.i.e Size value from Two.txt - Size Value from one.txt

Please note that table lengths i.e. number of rows may vary

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: _Which_ shell? There are quite a few.

Comment: operation will be : Two.txt (jobid 3)=77 - One.txt (Jobid 3)=33 =44  In same way for jobid 4 . Final o/p : 77-33=44, 88-44=44